# Pandas - convert columns to grouped array coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, scipy, euclidean-distance

I have a DataFrame of (x, y) coordinates that I would like to transform into array's to perform pairwise distance calculations on.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type':      ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
...                      'x': [1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 1, 3, 5],
...                      'y':   [2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6]})
```

Desired output - A new DataFrame of grouped/aggregated coordinates in an array so that I can apply a fuction to each array:

```
grp =       coordinates
    a    array([[1, 2],
               [3, 4],
               [5, 6]])

    b    array([[1, 2],
               [3, 4]])

    c    array([[1, 2],
               [3, 4],
               [5, 6]])
```

Distance calculation I wish to apply...

```
grp['distances'] = grp.apply(lambda x: scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(x['coordinates'], 'euclidean'), axis = 1)
```

I can't seem to get the groupby function to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new column with pairs x,y

```
df['xy'] = df.apply(lambda x: [x['x'], x['y']], axis=1)
```

groupby and aggregate into a list of lists

```
gb = df.groupby('type')
df2 = gb.aggregate({'xy': lambda x: list(x)})
```

this produces:

```
df2  
    xy
type    
a   [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
b   [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
c   [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

note that to apply your distance function you have to do:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
df2['distances'] = df2['xy'].apply(lambda x: distance.pdist(x, 'euclidean'))

df2

    xy                          distances
type        
a   [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]    [2.82842712475, 5.65685424949, 2.82842712475]
b   [[1, 2], [3, 4]]            [2.82842712475]
c   [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]    [2.82842712475, 5.65685424949, 2.82842712475]
```